# Can't access files via Local file API on Databricks

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to access small text file stored directly on dbfs using [local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#fuse).

I'm getting the following error.

> No such file or directory

My code:

```
val filename = "/dbfs/test/test.txt"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
  println(line)
}
```

At the same time I can access this file without any problems using dbutils or load it to RDD via spark context.

I've tried specifying the path starting with `dbfs:/` or `/dbfs/` or just with the test folder name, both in Scala and Python, getting the same error each time. I'm running the code from the notebook. Is it some problem with the cluster configuration?

Comment: BTW - I've just tested this code on community edition cluster, and it's working fine (on one node cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your cluster has Credentials Passthrough enabled. If so, local file Api is not available.

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis